# curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FTPPORT, str) on a remote computer - address is not available

Tags: ftp, libcurl

I am trying to use the function 'curl_easy_setopt' with 'CURLOPT_FTPPORT' option, for changing the mode from passive to active.

On the local computer the function is working as expected.

On the remote computer when I am using  `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FTPPORT, "-")` - there is a connection (I can see that in the filezilla-server log, also files are transferring).

But, when I am using `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FTPPORT, "TEST_STRING" )//TEST_STRING includes ip:port`, there is no connection. In the filezilla-server log the following information appears:

> bind (port=21) on non local address filed: address not available
>
> Rejected command, Requested IP address does not match control connection IP

my code:

```
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_FTPPORT, "192.168.19.19:21");
rc = curl_easy_perform(m_curl);
```

the rc returns CURL Error 28 - Timeout was reached.

In addition, I have tried several ports, and I have checked them with netstat command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value of [`CURLOPT_FTPPORT`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FTPPORT.html) is wrong.

- First, it cannot be port 21. It must be a free local port. On most systems it also has to be above 1024.
- And the IP address must be your local address, not the FTP server address. And it must be the address, from which the FTP server accepts your connection.

---

*And in general, you should use the passive mode, not the active mode. See my article on [FTP Connection Modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) for details.*